# What is the workflow file YAML config to use the GitHub-hosted apple silicon runner?

Tags: github-actions, apple-silicon

I feel like this is a dumb question but I cannot figure this out. I maintain a public Python app which has Cython elements which are needed to build the wheels. It's hosted on GitHub and uses their CICD system with workflows and actions and all that. We build for several versions of Python across Windows, Mac, and Linux.

So far we've only been building x86 Mac wheels since that's all that GitHub offers for their own hosted runners. (I know we can use self-hosted Apple Silicon runners but for now I've just been manually building the Mac ARM wheels on my laptop.)

All of the tracking issues from GitHub about the availability of GitHub hosted Mac ARM runners ([example](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/528)) have been closed today and link to [this blog post](https://github.blog/2023-10-02-introducing-the-new-apple-silicon-powered-m1-macos-larger-runner-for-github-actions/) which talks about larger runners, but those don't work and seem to cost money to use.

I've tried every [combination I can think of in my workflow file](https://github.com/missionpinball/mpf-mc/commits/python-311) to get an Apple Silicon runner to pick up a job that's hosted by GitHub, but I cannot figure out how to do it. And all of the issues, blog posts, etc. do not allow comments or discussion.

So, does anyone know how to use a GitHub hosted runner running Apple Silicon? Is that actually a feature that's available for free for open source projects?

Here are some examples of various iterations of my workflow file which did not work:

```
        - os: macos-latest
           python-version: 3.8
           cibw-build: cp38-macosx_universal2
         - os: macos-latest
           python-version: 3.9
           cibw-build: cp39-macosx_universal2
         - os: macos-latest
           python-version: '3.10'
           cibw-build: cp310-macosx_universal2
         - os: macos-latest
           python-version: 3.11
           cibw-build: cp311-macosx_universal2
```

```
        - os: macos-latest-arm64
           python-version: 3.8
           cibw-build: cp38-macosx_arm64
         - os: macos-latest-arm64
           python-version: 3.9
           cibw-build: cp39-macosx_arm64
         - os: macos-latest-arm64
           python-version: '3.10'
           cibw-build: cp310-macosx_arm64
         - os: macos-latest-arm64
           python-version: 3.11
           cibw-build: cp311-macosx_arm64
```

```
        - os: macos-13
           python-version: 3.8
           cibw-build: cp38-macosx_arm64
         - os: macos-13
           python-version: 3.9
           cibw-build: cp39-macosx_arm64
         - os: macos-13
           python-version: '3.10'
           cibw-build: cp310-macosx_arm64
         - os: macos-13
           python-version: 3.11
           cibw-build: cp311-macosx_arm64
```

```
        - os: ubuntu-latest
           python-version: 3.11
           cibw-build: cp311-manylinux_x86_64
         - os: macos-latest-xlarge
           python-version: 3.8
           cibw-build: cp38-macosx_arm64
         - os: macos-latest-xlarge
           python-version: 3.9
           cibw-build: cp39-macosx_arm64
         - os: macos-latest-xlarge
           python-version: '3.10'
           cibw-build: cp310-macosx_arm64
         - os: macos-latest-xlarge
           python-version: 3.11
           cibw-build: cp311-macosx_arm64
         - os: macos-latest
```

Comment: You can ask here: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/69211

Comment: Oh great. Thanks. I posted the question there.